# 401 Unauthorized for Options request to /oauth/token in spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I am using spring boot to make rest api and for login authentication m using spring security oauth2.it is working fine when i am sending request to localhost:8080/oauth/token from the angular client integrated with spring boot.(running on same localhost:8080).
But if i want to login from the client running on localhost(xampp) then it gives error as

[image]

**Updated**: I also hv this code in application.java file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
private static final String[] REQUEST_METHOD_SUPPORTED = { "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD" };

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
@Bean
CommandLineRunner init() {
    return (args) -> {
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File(FileUploadController.ROOT));

        Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(FileUploadController.ROOT));
    };
}
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("localhost:80")
            .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2");

        }
    };
 }


}
```

**OAuth2ServerConfiguration.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources
            .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        // @formatter:on
    }
    @Order(-1)
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()

        // @formatter:on
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);                            

        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("LMS");
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
        return tokenServices;
    }

}
```

}

I have checked and tried many solutions but cannot figure out.Any help please!!!!

Comment: Add a CORS filter and let OPTIONS bypass the filter

Comment: see updated question plz..isnt it enough to bypass?

Answer (score 3):

Option request is sent automatically to make sure the server is alive so you need to permit the option method in your security configuration, if you are using "WebSecurityConfgurerAdapter"

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

         httpSecurity.// your autherization configuration
          .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()


 }
```

Comment: http.authorizeRequests()    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"**").permitAll()    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()

Comment: try without '**' antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you passing some customer headers on request, you can see basic idea about CORS [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#how-does-it-work)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
            .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2");
        }
}
```

or you just configure

```
config.addAllowedHeader("*");
config.addAllowedMethod("*");
```

Please override your addCorsMappings according this and add update your headers in this method if you are passing any.

Comment: I have tried all these things everyone recommended but nothing is working.

Comment: can you please do two things I am updating my answer

Comment: .anyRequest().permitAll() add this to confirm

Comment: in which port you are running your angularjs app ?

Comment: i have tried this.not working.actually other endpoints are accessible by providing same headers but this login endpoint /oauth/token this is not working.no idea why

Comment: angular app is running with xampp..default 80 port.accessible at localhost/app

Comment: looks like these configs ain't affecting.no luck still

Comment: add whole class of where you added addCorsMappings method's class and SpringBootApplication class

Comment: where to add this?

Comment: have you used any Filters ?

Comment: tried once with filter but then removed it.because it overrides the config in application.java

Comment: then no idea without see whole project, if you using git then send it. I will lookinto when I get free

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue when implementing spring-security oauth2 with vuejs using oidc-client. So I figured out that the client-app has to be sent to the server via basic authentication which is not supported in the oidc-client library. The walkaround is to allow form authentication for the client as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
  }
}
```